# How to set localhost to an ip-adress in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, localhost

I got a project in my company running in jsf/primefaces.

In the context.xml, I would like to keep the tag  as it is, which mean that the attribute url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/some_name" stays as localhost.

How can i configure tomcat to redirect localhost to the real ip of the remote postgresql db, per say 10.2.32.32 ?

When I change localhost by 10.2.32.32, I can run the apps and access to the db without any proplem.

I would like to know if it's possible in the tomcat9 server running in eclipse to tell that localhost has to be redirect to 10.2.32.32 ?

Thanks by advance

EDIT
I've already tried to put all the Resource tag of the META-INF/context.xml inside the Context tag of the server, but i have this exception :
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory for one of my bean

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connexion refusée. Vérifiez que le nom de machine et le port sont corrects et que postmaster accepte les connexions TCP/IP.)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:655)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:733)
    at fr.lto.spad.legi.dao.CodeDAO.getProduit(CodeDAO.java:281)
    at fr.lto.spad.legi.bean.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connexion refusée. Vérifiez que le nom de machine et le port sont corrects et que postmaster accepte les connexions TCP/IP.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:144)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:370)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:651)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: Which `context.xml` file contains the URL? `META-INF/context.xml` is ignored by the way Eclipse starts applications, whereas `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` is specific to the server instance configured by Eclipse.

Comment: it's the project context.xml in webapps/META-INF/ that contains the url 
Only here the url is set

Maybe I can change some lines in the server.xml of the eclipse workspace tomcat server ? To make my tests I link some ResourceLink to my local directory instead of the server one and it's ok.
I just don't know how to do for the Context Resource area

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the `javax.sql.Exception`.

Comment: _"Connexion refusée. Vérifiez que le nom de machine et le port sont corrects et que postmaster accepte les connexions TCP/IP."_: did you try to connect to `10.2.32.32` with another Postgres client?

Comment: No, but when i set the url in Resource tag in META-INF/context.xml to 10.2.32.32
it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the /etc/hosts file and replace all localhost mapping to 10.2.32.32

Comment: I've tried that and the tomcat in eclipse won't run at all

Answer (score 0):

#### Bad solution

You can modify your `hosts` file to do this, although I would recommend not doing this.

The locations are as follows

- UNIX => `/etc/hosts` file
- Windows => `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

All you need is to modify this line and set your desired IP address instead of `127.0.0.1`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

#### Good solution

If you don't want to modify your file because it should not be committed, Git has a good solution. Just modify your file to what you need it to be, then tell git to ignore that specific file when scanning for changes

Here's how you tell git to ignore changes to a committed file(this differs from `.gitignore`, it just ignores new files)

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <YOUR FILE PATH>
```

And if you want to undo this and resume change tracking, simply go with this one

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <YOUR FILE PATH>
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, but I got to add a new ResourceLink in this context.xml

So of course, I could commit the context with localhost url, then put back the ip adresse to make it run in my local pc.

But I was wondering if there is some way to set the localhost as a dedicated ip, and only for the tomcat of this project

Answer (score 0):

The `META-INF/context.xml` file is only used if:

1. You deploy the application as WAR archive in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`,
2. You deploy the application as directory in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`.

Eclipse adds application descriptors **directly** in the `server.xml` file (the one you find in the `Servers` project). You can add the contents of `META-INF/context.xml` to the `<Context>` tag created by Eclipse and modify the URL.

Comment: I've already tried to put all the Resource tag of the META-INF/context.xml inside the Context tag of the server, but i have this exception :
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Comment: Did you use the correct URL and credentials for the database? The error message (or rather the primary cause of the exception) should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Yeah the url and credentials are correct, since if i test the url in the META-INF/context.xml the project runs good